# blob trigger azure function invoke a rest api

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Hi I'm having this scenario:

> User Upload a file to a blob storage account -> Azure function picks
> it up -> Call a rest api to perform some actions with the date inside
> the excel.

The azure function has a system assigned identity and both, the rest api and the function, resides inside the same resource group. The rest api is built using Azure app services.
I'm not sure on how to authenticate the Function app to call the REST api, is there any example on how should I proceed with authentication between Function App and REST api using Azure AD or system managed identity?

Is there another way of achieving this scenario that I'm not seeing?

Comment: What's the "REST API" built on?  An App Service?

Comment: Yes indeed it’s an app service

Comment: Since, system managed identity is already setup so  you can use [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication) library to generate the token for Rest API resource.

Comment: @user1672994, it's been superseded by Azure.Identity ...!

Comment: Thanks @Skin. Yes, Azure.Identity is better to use.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the App Service , You can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service#create-and-publish-a-web-app-on-app-service) to know how to secure your web app with the App Service authentication/authorization module and Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).

You can proceed with the authentication between the Function App and the Rest API by using Azure Active Directory as authentication provider. You have the option of creating a new app registration automatically or using an already registered registration.
This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) shows how to set up Azure App Service or Azure Functions authentication so that your app uses the Microsoft identity platform as the authentication provider.